# why pass more parameters to a function than it defines during a call()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js, call

In case the title is unclear:

```
var s = function(a,b){
  // do something 
}
s.call(thisArg,a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

In the above code, the `s` function has only 2 parameters, but when it is call()ed, it was passed 6 parameters, why would people do that? To simply evaluate c,d,e,f?

The real code is too long, so I can only post a screenshot here:
[image]

As you can see in the console, e[i][0] as a function is defined 3 parameteres, but when it is `call()`ed, it was passed 7 parameters, what is the purpose for this?

**If you are interested to see the actual code, it is here:** http://a.nycweb.io/components/com_community/assets/chat/chat.min.js

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code. Maybe the function uses `arguments` to access those parameters. Or, since this is minified code, maybe it was automatically generated to handle cases that don't actually matter in this specific circumstance

Comment: The code is here: http://a.nycweb.io/components/com_community/assets/chat/chat.min.js

Comment: @shenkwen please post the unminified version, it could be some minified magic

Comment: What was used to minimize the file?

Comment: Don't know. I was just trying to read and understand it.